# How to add multiple words to a string argument?

Tags: string, arguments, discord.py

So I was trying to make a command that can dm a user with a message. For the message, I used a string argument, and I tried using

```
message = ' '.join(args)
```

to connect multiple words into a single string. But, the bot is giving me an error stating:
"NameError: name 'args' is not defined."

Does anyone know why this is? Here is the full code if that helps.

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, message: str):
  
    message = ' '.join(args)
  

    await member.send(f"{message}")
    await ctx.send(f"User Dmed with {message}")
```

Comment: Think about it -- where have you defined `args` within your code?

Comment: Which `args` are you trying to join? Of course there will be an error because you are refering to a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm pretty new to discord.py, coding really. Can you please explain how I can define and tell which args to join?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really basic code, but this is how I would do it (you need to mention the user or provide the id):

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message: str):
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.send(f"User Dmed with {message}")
```